# Download apps that are listed as being incompatible with my device in the Play Store

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-play-store, installation

After installing Cyanogenmod on my Samsung S3 mini, I have found that the Play Store does not offer any additional apps. For some of the apps, I assume the only requirement I am missing is a newer version of Android, as I have been able to use them successfully when installed from a third party source (which is potentially dangerous).

I want to get apps that I know work with my device from the Play Store. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: And which are these additional apps the playstore should offer?

Comment: @xangua The only thing I could think about are CMTE themes, but they're visible anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Market Helper](http://codekiem.com/2013/02/13/market-helper/) works perfectly, if your device is rooted. It can spoof another device on a different carrier.